# Google Chrome weird refresh cache behavior

Tags: google-chrome

I'm developing a web app with Google Chrome and it is exhibiting this weird caching behavior. Usually, it caches some static resources. In the future, when those resources are needed, HTML requests will come back with code 304. Usually, if I do `Ctrl + F5`, the cache is supposedly refreshed, and requests for static content will always come back with code 200.

However, I occasionally encounter situation when the request comes back with code 200, but I still get the cached content instead of new content, after `Ctrl + F5`. I haven't been able to reproduce this, but I can only fetch new content by clearing cache this way:

[image]

Why doesn't `Ctrl + F5` automatically fetches all new content? Is there anyway to bypass all cache? And where are those cache files stored in the system? I have Windows 7.

Comment: I've been looking into this issue for years. I only seem to experience the problem when developing .Net code, but I haven't been able to establish a cause or a decent solution.

Very curious to know if you ever found a decent reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ctrl + F5` in the dev tools (F12) to make sure that you always get a full refresh of the cache.